# Can solr read the files which are stored in HDFS directly?

Tags: hadoop, solr, hdfs

My target files are stored in HDFS,How can solr take them to make index,or use API

Answer (score 0):

Solr has [support](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Running+Solr+on+HDFS) for keeping its indices in HDFS. But I think what you are asking is how to index content you have in HDFS, right?

If so, you can look at [this project](https://github.com/lucidworks/hadoop-solr) from Lucidworks that allows you to do that. Of course you can also just write some code to read the files yourself from HDFS and then index them into Solr with Solrj or HTTP apis.

There is an [open jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2096) but no activity...

Comment: thanks for your answer!Do you means solr has not support for indexing the  content stored in HDFS?